# Poker - Combination Questions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, card-games, poker

I'm struggling a bit with this question so any help will be very much appreciated!

The premise is that two people, call them A and B, are playing a variant of poker where there's 3 shared cards, and then they each draw 2 cards each. In this round, the 3 shared cards are an ace of hearts, a king of hearts and a queen of spades. Player A has an ace of diamonds and a queen of clubs, so he has two pairs.

Question 1: How many different pairs can player B draw that will result in a better hand than player A's?

Question 2: Assume another player joins in, how many different pairs of cards can they have so that both have a better hand than player A?

Now for question 1 I got the answer 27, which I'm pretty sure is wrong cause I feel like there should be a lot more. For question 2 I'm not even sure where to start. The only way I can think of doing it now is to just list out all the combinations and see which ones don't overlap but that can't be how you're supposed to do it.

Thanks!

EDIT: Quick explanation of how I got 27, don't have access to my notes so can't send a picture. First I looked at which poker hands that are better actually are possible to get, and they should be straight, three of a kind and two pair (ace and king). So the straights would be with a jack and 10, which I calculated by taking ${4 \choose 1}^2 = 16$. The two pair was ${3 \choose 1} \dot {2 \choose 1} = 6$. Now for the three of a kind I first did ${3 \choose 1} \dot {4 \choose 2} = 18$. I wasn't sure what the best way to calculate this was, but I came to the conclusion that 13 of those combinations would be missing due to some of the cards already being taken, so $18-3 = 5$. Then add them all up: $16 + 6 + 5 = 27$

Comment: Now edited to show my thought process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that there are $16$ possible straights.  You can choose any of $4$ jacks and any of $4$ tens, for a total of $16$ combinations.

There are $6$ possible AK pairs.  You can choose any of $2$ remaining aces and any of $3$ remaining kings for a total of $6$ more combinations.

There is $1$ possible hand resulting in three aces.  Player B would need both remaining aces.  Similarly there is $1$ possible hand resulting in three queens. There are $3$ possible hands resulting in three kings because Player B can choose $2$ of the $3$ remaining kings in $\binom 32 = 3$ different ways.

So the total is $16+6+1+1+3 = 27$ possible winning hands Player B can have and your answer was correct.

For part b, you really do have to operate by cases.

Comment: But 2 of the aces were already taken from the beginning, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, I was.  I'll revise.  Thanks for the catch.