# Poker Combination problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations, card-games, poker

A little while ago I made a post on here and this is basically a follow up to it as I ran into some problems.

Basically two people , player A and B, are playing a version of poker where there's 3 shared cards and they draw 2 cards each. My first problem was about calculating how many possible hands player B could win with. The answer for that is 27. Assume a third player C joins in. The problem I've gotten wrong is how many different pairs of cards can player B and C have so that both have a better hand than player A. My first thought was that because there are 27 winning hands, the max amount would be ${27 \choose 2} = 351$ without the restriction that they can't have the same card. My answer ended up being around 200, but apparently my first assumption is completely wrong as the real answer is 822.

All I want help with is understanding why my initial assumption of ${27 \choose 2}$ for the maximum amount is wrong. More context on the winning hands etc can be found here: [Poker - Combination Questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843817/poker-combination-questions)

Thanks!

Comment: In order for people to help you in this new query, which is much more complicated
than your older query, you will need to show some work, just as you did in the
older query.  In the older query, Robert Shore's answer provided details of 
how each of the 27 possible hands should be grouped.
The only way to solve the three person problem is to do just what Robert Shore
suggested: group the 27 possible hands by [16=J,10], [3=K,K], [1=Q,Q], [1=A,A],
[6=A,K].  Then, examine each of the 5 cases separately.

Comment: I'm mostly just interested in where I went wrong in my thinking that the max amount would be 351. I'm missing something because to me it makes sense that if there are 27 total combinations, and each person needs one of them, then the total amount (ignoring restrictions) would be ${27 \choose 2} = 351$

Comment: Sorry, the shortcut that you are suggesting, re $\binom{27}{2}$ will not work with this problem.  Take it one step at a time, and do **not** look for shortcuts.  Pick one specific case of the 5 cases in my previous note.  Do the work to try to enumerate all the possibilites represented by that case.  **Edit your query** to show your work.  Then mathSE reviewers will respond more positively.

Comment: I understand that it won't work and I'm not trying to look for shortcuts, I'm simply wondering why my thinking is incorrect because I feel like that might be what's hindering me from getting anywhere. I'm not interested in getting the whole problem solved for me, and I'll be editing my post to make that more clear. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Good point.  Consider the case of [16=J,10].  Now, with any one of those samples, 7 cards have been removed from the deck: [your hand = 1 Jack, 1 Ten], your [opponent's hand = 1A, 1Q], and the [community cards = 1A, 1K, 1Q].  Of the [52 - 7 = 45] cards remaining, how many of the $\binom{45}{2}$ combinations result in the 3rd person also beating the AQ hand.  Take the # of satisfying combinations from the $\binom{45}{2}$ in this instance, and multiply it by 16.  ...see next comment

Comment: This yields all of possible ways that you and the 3rd person can both beat the AQ hand, with respect to the specific case of [you have J,10].  You have 6 different cases to examine.  With each case, the # of combinations from the $\binom{45}{2}$ that will have the 3rd player also beat AQ will **potentially** vary from case to case.  This is what gives this complicated problem its *flavor*.

Comment: I see, that makes it a bit clearer. I'll be giving it a go again, thank you for the help.

Comment: Typo re previous comment :"You have 6 different cases..." should be "You have 5 different cases...".